# Full page Background strange Cut off

Tags: css, background, background-image

In my website I have made a custom login page everything is almost working great but the full page background image.

The background image is showing up fine but if you resize the window that you get scrollbars you get a white bar on the bottom of the page and on mobile you get it too. How would I fix this problem.

I have tried everything I know it should be a easy fix but I do not understand why I can't fix it.

---

I have tested and those will not work

```
html,body{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%}
body.login{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%}
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

---

**SOLUTION**

```
html {
    background: url('images/yourimage.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.images/body-bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}

body.login{background: transparent;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `height:100%;` declaration on your `html, body`.

It is causing the body to not exceed 100% (the viewport), so that the area outside the viewport (visible on scroll) no longer has the background because the body is too small to fill that area of the screen.

Comment: Thanks this fixes it but there is one catch Wordpress adds it automatically. How to get rid of it?

Comment: Adds it automatically in what way? If you are building a Wordpress theme, you should be able to control this within the CSS file.

Comment: Wordpress adds it automatically from its core css files. And I would like not to touch touch files and leave them intact.

Comment: Is there another way of fixing this?

Comment: Never encountered that when working with Wordpress. This is the best/simplest way. If you are worried about messing with other Wordpress pages, you can add it dynamically only to the login screen. Are you creating a theme, or is this something else? If it is your own theme, then you should have complete control...

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the body.login css selector to html and add body.login background: transparent;

```
html {
        background: url('images/yourimage.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.images/body-bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
    }

    body.login{background: transparent;}
```